# How do you get a list of all the _design documents for a given database in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, couchdbkit

I have searched all over and can't figure out how to get a list of all the design documents for a specific database in CouchDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is how using a straight HTTP call.

```
http://localhost:5984/mydatabase/_all_docs?startkey=%22_design%22&endkey=%22_design0%22
```

here is how to get all _design documents and their views for all databases using [couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from couchdbkit import *

server = Server()
dbs = server.all_dbs()
for dbname in dbs:
    db = server.get_or_create_db(dbname)
    result = db.all_docs(startkey='_design', endkey='_design0')
    for doc in result.all():
       designdoc = db.get(doc['id'])
       if 'views' in designdoc:
           for view in designdoc['views']:
              print '%s/%s/_view/%s' % (dbname, designdoc['_id'], view)
```

Comment: Awesome! You may want to check for _design%2F because _designblah is not a design doc however in practice it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Meant to say: `_design/` through `_design0`. And maybe leave a comment in your source to remind you that '0' comes after '/'

Comment: I used firebug to figure out how Futon does the query